# package for detecting users contry in php?

Tags: php, ip, country

I want to know what is the best package to detect country which user is visiting from?

I am using php/mysql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is not a guaranteed way but there are some options:

- You can use [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/geoip)
- You can check the [`HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`](http://www.phptutorial.info/scripts/languages.php) header(`$_SERVER`)
- Use any [IP-To-Country](http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/book/print/5) database

Comment: I had no idea this was already baked into PHP. It looks like it's designed as an interface to MaxMind's DB, is that right?

Comment: Are you talking about GeoIP? I think you are right. I found some MaxMind link on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/geoip.setup.php

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [MaxMind GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) database, and use that to lookup the IP of user to determine their country.

There are paid versions of that database, but I've found the accuracy of the free database more than sufficient.

Comment: thanks.. Is there any proxy package availble for testing ..

Comment: @Padma: I'm not sure. I didn't play with it very much, so the only testing I did was "hey friend-in-another-country, what's your IP address?"